# Where can I get all mathematician's birth day and death day?

Tags: reference-request, math-history, education

Did anyone do some some similar statistic thing?

wiki's page is too few.

[mathematician in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_mathematicians)

For example, I want to know which day/ month that most mathematicians be born or died.

Comment: Most mathematicians haven't died yet, so this will be difficult to do.

Comment: And even more weren't born yet.

Comment: @GitGud I agree with the hint to not-yet-born mathematicians. But "even more"??

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm afraid I forgot that probably most will eventually die.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, Old mathematicians never die, they just lose some of their functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best resource is probably http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/

Comment: http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Day_files/Day303.html
There are two Halmos, I don't why?

Comment: Perhaps Halmos was born-again. Or perhaps it was like the Piranha brothers, "Doug was born in February 1929 and Dinsdale two weeks later; and again a week after that." http://www.intriguing.com/mp/_scripts/piranha.php